# Memory usage of matrix object reported in RStudio

Tags: r, memory, rstudio, profiling

Suppose I have a large matrix `x` of type `numeric` with 1e4 * 1e4 elements.

`x` should require 1e8 * 8/ 1e6 = 800MB memory (plus some header). This is confirmed by `object.size()` and `pryr::object_size()`:

```
> x <- matrix(NA_real_, nrow = 1e4, ncol = 1e4)
> object.size(x)
800000216 bytes
> pryr::object_size(x)
800 MB
```

However, size reported in the 'environment' tab is 762.9MB.

How does *RStudio* calculate memory usage of objects reported in the 'environment' tab of *RStudio* and where does the difference come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RStudio shows you the same memory size as `object.size`. A MB contains 1024KB and a KB contains 1024B:

```
object.size(x)
# 800000216 bytes
object.size(x) / 1024 / 1024
# 762.9 bytes
```

I tried looking in the `pryr::object_size` code but it is implemented in C. I took a look in the [source code](https://github.com/hadley/pryr/blob/master/src/object_size.cpp) and it looks like the calculation of bytes is like this:

```
 double bytes = 0;
  // Big vectors always allocated in 8 byte chunks
  if      (n_bytes > 16) bytes = n_bytes * 8;
  // For small vectors, round to sizes allocated in small vector pool
  else if (n_bytes > 8)  bytes = 128;
  else if (n_bytes > 6)  bytes = 64;
  else if (n_bytes > 4)  bytes = 48;
  else if (n_bytes > 2)  bytes = 32;
  else if (n_bytes > 1)  bytes = 16;
  else if (n_bytes > 0)  bytes = 8;

  return bytes;
}
```

So probably that's why your calculation is for 800MBs which matches pryr.